# How to fix '[error] submission with curl() was not successful' in Octave, Coursera ML exercise?

Tags: windows, octave

I'm unable to submit the programming exercise of the ML course by AndrewNg on Coursera. Whenever I try to submit the assignment, the following error pops up and submission fails.

> [error] submission with curl() was not successful
>   warning: `findstr` is obsolete; use `strfind` instead

I've tried upgrading the version of the Octave used, but the error still pops up. While running the code, the result is absolutely correct though.

Comment: There are [several similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boctave%5D+coursera+submit+is%3Aq) on Stack Overflow. Have you looked at the solutions for those?

Comment: what is your operating system? do you have curl installed on your operating system? does your code run without errors when you run it by itself?

Comment: Please add a link to your used script. I've found submitWithConfiguration.m on github and this one I've found first tries to use urlread and then curl (which has to be available) so please add a breakpoint around line 136 and check why urlread fails and if curl is acessible

Comment: @beaker I did go through those questions, but I don't seem to find a solution.

Comment: I'm new to Octave. So I'm not very sure about how the code works. I am able to get the plots corrects and I checked it for the expected output. No I don't have curl installed.

Comment: @Nisha have you found a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah if you are using UNIX based systems try doing

```
 sudo apt install curl
```

do this in the terminal , it worked for me. I'm assuming this is Andrew NG's ML course